# Problems with JS Mergesort overloading the stack

Tags: javascript

So, I have this algorithm for mergeSort but cant seem to get it to work within JS. I'm getting maximum call stack exceeded when trying to run it and i cannot figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
export const doMergeSort = (array) => {
    const mergeSort = arr => {
        
        let mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2),
            left = mergeSort(arr.slice(0, mid)),
            right = mergeSort(arr.slice(mid));
      
        return merge(left, right);
      };

    const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
        let sorted = [];
      
        while (arr1.length && arr2.length) {
          if (arr1[0] < arr2[0]) sorted.push(arr1.shift());
          else sorted.push(arr2.shift());
        };
      
        sorted.concat(arr1.slice().concat(arr2.slice()));
      };

      mergeSort(array);
      
      
}
```

Comment: In `mergeSort()`, you immediately recursively call `mergeSort` regardless of what parameters were passed to the function, regardless of the array's length, regardless of any condition.

Comment: Well your recursion has no base case.

Answer (score 0):

`mergeSort()` calls itself in an unending [recursive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) loop. I made an example to demonstrate - just run it to see

```js
const maxCallCount = 5
let callCount = 0;

const mergeSort = arr => {
  // Output and exit when we loop too many times
  callCount += 1;
  console.log(`${callCount}. mergeSort(${JSON.stringify(arr)})`);
  if (callCount >= maxCallCount) {
    console.log('...');
    return;
  }

  // Your code (it never executes past these lines)
  let mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2),
      left = mergeSort(arr.slice(0, mid)); // recursive call
};

// Call mergeSort, kicking off the recursive loop
mergeSort([ 1, 2 ]);
```